# Не работает соединение с MySQL в blazor

Tags: c#, mysql, blazor

В webassambly blazor (.net 6) не работает соединение с MySQL. Выскакивает ошибка **"The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception"**. Тот же код в консольном приложении и в blazor server работает без проблем.

```
@page "/counter"
@using MySql.Data.MySqlClient

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p role="status">Current name: @name</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private string name = "";

    private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(@"server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; database=database; username=root; password=mypass;");
    private MySqlCommand command;
    private MySqlDataReader reader;

    public string Query(string sql)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                s = reader["Name"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            s = ex.Message;
        }
        return s;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        name = Query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE ID = 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст исключения какой? Там есть inner exception?

Comment: Только это исключение получаю The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception

Comment: Это только говорит о том, где произошло исключение, но не указывает на причину.

Comment: Наконец нашел InnerException. Вышло вот это "The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception".

Comment: Это опять место, где возникло исключение, а не его текст. Копайте глубже.

Comment: Через метод GetBaseException нашел только вот это: "Мalue cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')"

Comment: Множество библиотек не будут работать на платформе browser. Если ли есть доступ к исходникам, какие-то не сильно сложные можно и вылечить, но вот клиент к СУБД вообще не факт, что удастся.